# Admin panel on my domain says wrong user & password . databsse, phpmyadmin related problem?

Tags: php, database

I have a problem logging into a domain admin panel that is connected to my app.

I get wrong username and password, even though I have copying the username and password from `tbl_admin` from phpmyadmin.

this is from my phpmyadmin SQL Structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

/////////////////////code below is my function.php from filemanager////////////////////////////////////

```
#Admin Login
function adminUser($username, $password)
{

    global $mysqli;

    $sql = "SELECT id,username FROM tbl_admin where username = '".$username."' and password = '".md5($password)."'";       
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows > 0)
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $_SESSION['ADMIN_ID'] = $row['id'];
                        echo $_SESSION['ADMIN_USERNAME'] = $row['username'];

        return true; 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I should hope that the password you have in your database is a hash of some sort, and not the actual password

Comment: Domain panel password is different from table password.

Comment: in the SQL file from phpmyadmin i have a tbl_admin where i have the admin login credentials to my adminpanel login system. it just say wrong password. anyone wanna take a look please?

Comment: How you insert password to database? Maybe you use md5 or sha1?

Comment: Yes. i have insert the whole login credentials to database. still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

At your query

```
$sql = "SELECT id,username FROM tbl_admin where username = '".$username."' and password = '".md5($password)."'";
```

you compares your password to password coded to md5 at database row.
If you try to copy a password directly from table tbl_admin remove md5 command at you query

```
$sql = "SELECT id,username FROM tbl_admin where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."' LIMIT 1;" ;
```

Then you can copy a password from your tbl_admin.
If you want to keep md5 command at you query you have to know a password before coding to md5 string.

```
LIMIT 1
```

is for faster mysql preformance

Comment: tried it, didnt work, something is wrong with my php somewhere,

Comment: How your password looks like, and what you enter at your form?